# how to get userproperties from servicebus-triggered message?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a method triggered by servicebus:

```
    public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(
            "antrox-topic",
            "antrox-subscritpion",
            Connection = "ServicebusConnectionString")]string message,
            IDictionary<string, object> UserProperties,
            ILogger log)
```

**How do we get the value of UserProperties without using TryGetValue? Can we bind to the values?**

Suppose I know that `UserProperties`  has a key called `SourceParty`, can I simply change the method signature to something like this:

```
    public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(
            "antrox-topic",
            "antrox-subscritpion",
            Connection = "ServicebusConnectionString")]string message,
            IDictionary<string, object> UserProperties,
            string SourceParty, //change made here <-----------
            ILogger log)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported, firstly this is a custom property it's not the service bus message property and then you could check the `ServiceBusTriggerBinding.cs` , you could find all supported bindings.

Here is the [binding code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/42a711763ddecca9df4caae9c7dc5fe16178880c/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/Triggers/ServiceBusTriggerBinding.cs#L112), in here you could find some bindings not list in the doc like MessageReceiver, however no custom property or related binding, so you have to use `UserProperties` binding or bind the message to `Message` class then get the UserProperties from Message class.